# Azure Devops - Importing git repo from another organization links to work items in another project

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I imported several git repos to Azure Devops. They were previously hosted on Azure Server 2019 (On premise version of Azure Devops):

```
git remote add origin git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/MyOrg/MyProj
git push -u origin --all
```

I noticed the commit history showing work items from an entirely different project than the one I imported to.

So I deleted the repos.  I had used azure devops migrations tools to import the Iterations, Areas, and Work Items for this project from on-prem, so I thought it was an issue with this tool.  But, I re-pushed the repo to azure devops, and the unrelated work items were once again updated with links to git commits, some of them entirely different.

Is this a bug with Azure DevOps?

Can I clean up the links without impacting the work item?

Comment: The commit messages likely contain references to work item IDs in the format `#1234`. You'd need to figure out what the remapped work item IDs are and rewrite the commit messages with the correct ID, or simply rewrite the commit messages to not contain an ID at all.

Comment: Awesome thank you!! I will look into this solution.

Comment: The thing is, the work items are showing that I updated them, at both import times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should explore the ["Import a repository" option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#import-into-an-existing-empty-repo).

> [image]
>
> The import feature disables automated linking for work items mentioned
> in a commit comment since the work item IDs in the destination project
> might not be the same as ones in the source project. Automatic linking
> for work items mentioned in a commit can be re-enabled by navigating
> to Settings, Version Control, selecting your repository, and choosing
> Options. For more information on linking commits with work items, see
> [How do I associate my commits with work items?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-associate-my-commits-with-work-items)

Comment: I was getting errors using the import function, I believe because of 2 factor authentication.  But this tells me the push automatically updated these work items with links.